# How to substitute default ASP.NET MVC controller to your own implementation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, controller

In my ASP.NET MVC applications, all controller I create via Visual Studio UI are inherited from `Controller` class. I use my own version of a base controller class that I need all my controller to inherit from. Is there a mechanism that would allow me to bypass the manual rewriting of Controller inheritance and put my own BaseController automatically.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to inherit all controllers of your own base class, but without having to manually change this?

Comment: Yes, correct, thank you for clearing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your machine is setup you can browse to your VS installation and make a few changes.

On my machine the location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddController`

You can modify `Controller.tt` (a T4 template).

Make a backup of this file if you'll need to revert :)

**Update!**

Qpirate pointed me to a link in the comments below.

[From Scott Hanselmans Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) This is an even easier way to create your own version without affecting the global ones.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about using T4 templates, but didn't know Visual Studio already used T4 for generating the controllers.

Comment: @Steven Yeah they do .. what i need to find out is how to create my own project type .. so i can instantly add all my "cruft" i usually add when developing :)

Comment: actually you can inherit these Templates in your solution here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx